# MySQL disconnects when innodb_buffer_pool_size > 75% RAM

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

For now innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 12GB (out of 16GB memory), and when I try to increase this value (12.5GB or even up to 13G) to max out performance, MySQL suddenly disconnects itself from the client. I'm having hard time figuring out what would be the issue here.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses memory for other needs other than the MySQL innodb buffer pool.  By increasing the buffer pool, you are causing MySQL to run out of memory.  When MySQL runs out of memory, MySQL automatically shuts down and restarts.

You can see this info in the MySQL error log.

To increase performance, try to look for slow queries (slower than 1-2 seconds) instead, and analyze the explain plan and indexes.  Queries that scan many rows and dont use proper indexes cause severe performance issues.  This will help a lot more than increasing the buffer pool.